# Controls do not appear on dynamically created user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, dynamic-controls

I have user control named DateTimeUC which has two textboxes on its markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="timeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am dynamically creating this control in another user control:

```
Controls.Add(GenerateDateTime(parameter));
private DateTimeUC GenerateDateTime(SomeParameter parameter)
{
    DateTimeUC uc = new DateTimeUC();
    uc.ID = parameter.Name;
    return uc;
}
```

But when I render the page, DateTimeUC renders nothing. I checked it like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter(builder);
    HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);
    base.Render(hwriter);
    string s = builder.ToString();
}
```

s is empty and Controls.Count is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use the `LoadControl( "your_user_control_app_relative_path.ascx" )` method instead of "DateTimeUC uc = new DateTimeUC();"

Comment: Been looking for an answer to this all day. Thanks!

Comment: How can I load a user control that is embedded in a dll?

Comment: @Zolomon: You need the *.ascx file. The *.ascx file contains the asp.net markup which is used for autogenerated class. The autogenerated class inherits from class in assembly (*.dll).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself a while back.  You need to use the LoadControl() method.  Check out [this page](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/leon/archive/2004/08/28/23559.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add your control to the page's form & not the form itself.

your code:

```
Controls.Add( GenerateDateTime(parameter) );
```

try:

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add( GenerateDateTime(parameter) );
```